# Restrict console input by character type

Tags: java, console-application

I currently have a simple function (posted below) which asks the user a question and expects to have an integer answer.

Is there a way to make java restrict the characters that can be entered into the console i.e. only allow numbers to be entered.

I know there are simple ways to do this in other programming languages but How should I go about doing this in java and implementing it into my function?

```
    static int questionAskInt(String question)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print (question+"\n");
    System.out.print ("Answer: ");
    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Scanner.hasNextInt`, and while loop, you can restrict the user to give input, until it passes an `integer` value.

```
while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer answer");
    scan.next();
} 
return scan.nextInt();
```

or, you can also give a certain number of chances (so that it does not go into `infinite loop`, by using a count variable: -

```
int count = 3;

while (count > 0 && !scan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer answer");
    System.out.println("You have " + (count - 1) + "more chances left.");
    count--;
    scan.next();
}

if (count > 0) {
    return scan.nextInt();
}

return -1;
```

Comment: currently after trying to enter some characters that are not an int and pressing enter this falls into an endless loop spamming "Please enter an integer answer" is there a better way?

Comment: @mr.user1065741.. Try out the second way I posted.

Comment: You probably want to use scan.nextLine() to skip the line of invalid input.

Comment: Wouldn't that just spam those two lines three times?

Comment: @mr.user1065741. Yeah, it would. But there won't be any issue with it.

Comment: Adding scan.nextLine(); after the println command seemed to stop the spamming issue! Thanks @Neil

Comment: @mr.user1065741. Ah! sorry, you needed to use `scan.next()` after `count--`.